# Fragment in DrawerLayout not showing

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout

I want to show a fragment in drawerlayout view. I have an activity layout like this :

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/filter_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_happay"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs_dashboard"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/accent"
                app:tabMode="fixed" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_filter_frag_place_holder"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:clickable="true" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I want to show a drawer when menu item is clicked. I add a fragment to the frame layout at runtime like this :

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(rlFilterView.getId(), FilterFragment.newInstance(currentFrag.getContentType(), "activity",this)).commit();
```

The problem is the fragment is not showing up but I can see the translucent overlay of drawer layout on menu click. This same code works on other layouts. Need help!

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.androhub.com/navigation-view-material-design-support-library-tutorial/) for material Navigation View and this [link](http://www.androhub.com/android-navigationdrawer/) for old navigation drawer.

Comment: put your framelayout inside of your coordinatorlayout